# UIPageViewController second and third page flickers to white

Tags: ios, swift, uipageviewcontroller

I have a `pageviewcontroller`, but when I swipe to the second page, it shows the right controller for a split second and then the screen goes white, if I then swipe again it will show up as it should be. It also has 4 pages instead of my intended 3 pages.

Here is a video to demonstrate the problem: https://streamable.com/i1inq

The indexing is as following:

```
 profileController.index = 0
 discoverController.index = 1
 matchController.index = 2

func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfter viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController?
{
    if index == 0
    {
        index = discoverController.index
        return discoverController
    }
    else if index == 1
    {
        index = matchController.index
        return matchController
    }

    return nil
}
```

EDIT: I should also mention that the initial controller is the profileController, and so the index starts at 0 when the app is run.

Comment: can you please use scrollview with pagination. I think it's very help full for you. otherwise try to add child view of another viewcontroller in parentviewcontroller.

Comment: Will you share your demo?

Comment: Do not cache `index`. User `index` in vc from argument of method: `viewControllerAfter viewController: UIViewController` .

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Updated**

You can simply modify your code customized viewcontroller with `index` property:

```
func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfter viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController?
{
    let index = (viewController as? MyCustomVCWithIndexForPageViewController).index
    if index == 0
    {
        index = discoverController.index
        return discoverController
    }
    else if index == 1
    {
        index = matchController.index
        return matchController
    }

    return nil
}
```

**Original**

You should not cache parameter related to pageviewcontroller.
`UIPageViewController` sometimes `preload` your page to have a better performance.

Ex:

You have 3 pages to display.

You are now displaying first page initial.

Then you scroll to second view. `viewControllerAfter` called with `viewController` of first viewcontroller for requesting second viewcontroller.

And `viewControllerAfter` called again with `viewController` of second viewcontrollerfor requesting third viewcontroller (preload).

In this case if you cache index, it will lead to unpredictable results.

Comment: Ahh I see, makes sense. Do you know of a solution that works?

Comment: Mohammadalijf's answer should works. Or you can see my update answer

Answer (score 4):

you didnt provide enough code to detect what is causing the problem. but this is how i usually use UIPageController

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var pages = [UIViewController]()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // add pages to the array
        // ...
    }
}

extension ViewController: UIPageViewControllerDataSource {

    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController,
                            viewControllerAfter viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        // find index of viewcontroller in array
        if let index = pages.index(of: viewController) {
            switch index {
                // if index is last item you should return first item
            case pages.count - 1:
                return pages[0]
            default:
                // by default return next item in array
                return pages[index + 1]
            }
        }
        return nil
    }

    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController,
                            viewControllerBefore viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        // find index of viewcontroller in array
        if let index = pages.index(of: viewController) {
            switch index {
                // if index is 0 you should return last item in array
            case 0:
                return pages[pages.count - 1]
            default:
                // by default return previous item in array
                return pages[index - 1]
            }
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```